# Getting Error: [Errno 95] Operation not supported while writing zip file in databricks

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, zip, databricks

Here i am trying to zip the file and write that to one folder (mount point) using below code in Databricks.

```
# List all files which need to be compressed
import os
modelPath  = '/dbfs/mnt/temp/zip/'
filenames = [os.path.join(root, name) for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top=modelPath , topdown=False) for name in files]
print(filenames)

zipPath = '/dbfs/mnt/temp/compressed/demo.zip'
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile(zipPath, 'w') as myzip:
  for filename in filenames:
    print(filename)
    print(myzip)
    myzip.write(filename)
```

But I am getting error as [Errno 95] Operation not supported.

Error Details

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2086761864237851> in <module>
     15     print(myzip)
---> 16     myzip.write(filename)

/usr/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py in write(self, filename, arcname, compress_type, compresslevel)
   1775             with open(filename, "rb") as src, self.open(zinfo, 'w') as dest:
-> 1776                 shutil.copyfileobj(src, dest, 1024*8)
   1777 

/usr/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py in close(self)
   1181                 self._fileobj.write(self._zinfo.FileHeader(self._zip64))
-> 1182                 self._fileobj.seek(self._zipfile.start_dir)
   1183 

OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py in close(self)
   1837                     if self._seekable:
-> 1838                         self.fp.seek(self.start_dir)
   1839                     self._write_end_record()

OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2086761864237851> in <module>
     14     print(filename)
     15     print(myzip)
---> 16     myzip.write(filename)

/usr/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
   1310 
   1311     def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
-> 1312         self.close()
   1313 
   1314     def __repr__(self):

/usr/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py in close(self)
   1841             fp = self.fp
   1842             self.fp = None
-> 1843             self._fpclose(fp)
   1844 
   1845     def _write_end_record(self):

/usr/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py in _fpclose(self, fp)
   1951         self._fileRefCnt -= 1
   1952         if not self._fileRefCnt and not self._filePassed:
-> 1953             fp.close()
   1954 
   1955
```

Could anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Note: Here i can zip the file using shutil, but i want avoid driver so using above approch.

Comment: which databricks are you using? azure, aws or community edition?

Comment: Azure Databricks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide details of your mount, probably it's Blob Storage or ADLSv2 and apparently it doesn't allow file seek.

Check out this simple snippet:

```
%python

path = '/dbfs/mnt/temp/testfile'

with open(path, "w") as f:
    f.write("test")
    f.seek(1)
    f.write("x")

with open(path, "r") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

It will throw "Operation not supported" at `f.seek(1)`.

Repeat the same with `path = '/tmp/testfile'` and you'll get correct result ("txst").

Weird thing is that the seek in zipfile.py should not be reached at all, it looks like `self._seekable` returned incorrect value, I'm not sure if that's a problem of the library or Azure.

Anyway, just create the archive in local directory and move it to the mount afterwards.

```
tempPath = '/tmp/demo.zip'
zipPath = '/dbfs/mnt/temp/compressed/demo.zip'
import zipfile
import os

with zipfile.ZipFile(tempPath, 'w') as myzip:
  for filename in filenames:
    print(filename)
    print(myzip)
    myzip.write(filename)

os.rename(tempPath, zipPath)
```

Comment: above code is working fine but want to understand what is **local directory** i.e dbfs path or databricks driver. And also when i am trying to list the files in /tmp i was not able to find the demo.zip. could you please elaborate more that will help us to understand.

Comment: You run code in a [cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/), that is a group of VMs, local directory is just a directory on their filesystem. Also you have DBFS mounted under node's `/dbfs` directory and under 'dbfs:/mnt/temp' you have your Azure storage mounted (or `/dbfs/mnt/temp` as seen by the node).

Comment: If you run this you won't see `/tmp/demo.zip`, because it was *moved* by `os.rename` into DBFS. If you copy the file instead of moving it, it will remain under `/tmp` (at least until you shut down the cluster...) Read the docs about [clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/) and [DBFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dbfs/) to be fully aware of what is persistent and what's only scoped to cluster's lifetime.