# How to zip two files in Databricks?

Tags: python, file, zip, databricks, parquet

I have two files stored in `'dbfs/tmp/folder/'` I am trying to zip the files, although the code runs with no error but the created .zip file cannot be seen in the folder. What is the best way to zip two files in Databricks?

code:-

```
file_paths = ['/dbfs/dbfs/tmp/folder1/test1.parquet', 
              '/dbfs/dbfs/tmp/folder1/test2.parquet']
zip_name = 'myzip.zip'
zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_name, "w")
for file in file_paths:
  zip_file.write(file)
zip_file.close()
```

Executes with no error but the zipped folder cannot been seen under `'/dbfs/dbfs/tmp/folder1/'`

Comment: Where are you running the script from? From your script, you are storing the output zip file in your current directory.

Comment: @TYZ I am running in databricks notebook and Iam storing the same directory where the files are present.

Comment: Please try to change `'myzip.zip'` to the full path and see if it works or not.

Comment: @TYZ Yes I have tried that as well it says OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported

Comment: Seems like the issue is more on Databricks side, see this discussion: https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/705

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default file will be created on the local disk of the driver node. But you can't put `/dbfs/...` as output destination because of the DBFS limitations, described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75853317/getting-error-errno-95-operation-not-supported-while-writing-zip-file-in-data?noredirect=1).  What you'll need is:

1. Write file to the local disk into the know location, for example, `zip_name = 'myzip.zip'`
2. When file is written, copy it to the DBFS using `dbutils.fs.cp` command using `file:` as prefix for the local file name:

```py
zip_name = '/tmp/myzip.zip'
zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_name, "w")
for file in file_paths:
  zip_file.write(file)
zip_file.close()
# copy file from local disk to DBFS...
dbutils.fs.cp(f"file:{zip_name}", zip_name)
```